# Git : How to Push missing branches from one repo to another repo

Tags: android, git, github, version-control, repository

I have a Repo Repo1 and I have 10 branches in Repo1. I have created a new Repo Repo2 and I have pushed all the code from Repo1 to Repo2. But I am able to see only 6 branches in Repo2 out of 10 branches which were present in Repo1.

My Remote for Repo1 is `AndroidOld`

My Remote for Repo2 is `Android`

Url for Repo1 is `https://github.com/XYZ/Repo1.git`
Url for Repo2 is `https://github.com/ABC/Repo2.git`

I have tried the following commands seeing other SO Links:
`git push --all AndroidOld
git push AndroidOld --mirror
git push Android refs/remotes/AndroidOld/*:refs/heads/*`

But Nothing worked, please let me know how can I push the missing branches to new Repo

Comment: do u want to duplicate Repo1

Comment: @vm345 Yes, I tried doing that but I missed few branches so I want to add missed branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s caused there are only 6 local branches in AndroidOld repo. The **other 4 branches do not checkout to local AndroidOld repo**.

You can double check by the command `git branch`, it will list the 6 branches you pushed to Android repo.

To push the other 4 branches (the missing branches) to Android repo, you need to checkout the 4 branches and then push again:

```
git checkout missing_branch1
git checkout missing_branch2
git checkout missing_branch3
git checkout missing_branch4
git push Android --mirror
```

Then the 10 branches will be pushed to Android repo.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** 
Make sure you have a local copy of all "old repo"
branches and tags.
Fetch all of the remote branches and tags:

```
git fetch origin
```

View all "old repo" local and remote branches:

```
git branch -a
```

If some of the remotes/ branches doesn't have a local copy,
checkout to create a local copy of the missing ones:

```
git checkout -b <branch> origin/<branch>
```

Now we have to have all remote branches locally.

**2.** Add a "new repo" as a new remote origin:

```
git remote add new-origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

**3.** Push all local branches and tags to a "new repo".
Push all local branches (note we're pushing to new-origin):

```
git push --all new-origin
```

Push all tags:

```
git push --tags new-origin
```

**4.** Remove "old repo" origin and its dependencies.
View existing remotes (you'll see 2 remotes for both fetch and push)

```
git remote -v
```

Remove "old repo" remote:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Rename "new repo" remote into just 'origin':

```
git remote rename new-origin origin
```

Comment: Thanks.I do not want to create a new repo again, I want to add only missing branches from old repo to new one

Comment: simply skip the second part then

Comment: This did it for me. git checkout -b missing upstream/missing ;  git push --all origin                             
;